# File transfer between git and AWS S3 without having to download file locally

Tags: java, git, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to transfer files bidirectionally between Amazon s3 and git repository using java. Is there any way I can transfer it directly without downloading the file locally and uploading again?

Answer (score 0):

The code is not tested, but will give you ideas:

```
   BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL("www.somewhere.com/file.pdf").openStream());

   //Use Commons IO IOUtils:
   byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);


    PutObjectRequest objectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
            .bucket(bucketName)
            .key(key)
            .build();


    //Send it to S3
    s3.putObject(objectRequest, RequestBody.fromBytes(bytes);
```

Comment: This will also be pulling the file locally right and keeping in memory. My files will be too large -more that a GB , so i am looking for something hich can directly transfer the file between aws and git, not putting load on my service

Comment: you are right @Jerry, it would be using the memory instead.

I have not come across such a scenario where using Java you would stream an object from Server A to Server B without an interaction in the middle.